# prepare branch for merge request

Tags: git, git-branch

To work on a feature I spawn a new `feature` branch from `development`, work on it and submit a merge request (MR) to `development`. During my work on `feature`, the `development` branch can change a lot.

To avoid merge conflicts I merge latest `development` into `feature` before submitting my MR, and my commits on `feature` are mixed with tons of other commits from `development`, makes commit history quite ugly, I guess harder to review too.

I thought of this, when ready for MR: 
Instead of merging `development` into `feature`, create new branch `feature-mr` from latest `development`, then merge or cherry-pick from `feature` to `feature-mr`, and finally submit MR of `feature-mr` to `development`.

I wonder if there is a common practice for this common problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`git rebase development`](https://git-scm.herokuapp.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing).

Your repository looks like this, with `feature` behind `development`.

```
A - B - C - D - E [development]
     \
      F - G - H [feature]
```

`git rebase development` will replay each patch in feature on top of development.  Sort of like cherry picking F, G and H.  You wind up with this.

```
A - B - C - D - E [development]
     \           \
      F - G - H   F1 - G1 - H1 [feature]
```

F, G and H will eventually be garbage collected.  It takes weeks, so you can go back to them if the rebase messes up.

You can update your repository and rebase `feature` in one step with `git pull --rebase origin development`.  This will do a `git fetch origin` but then `git rebase origin/development` instead of `git merge origin/development`.  Note that your local `development` branch will not be updated, you'll have to do that.  If this confuses you, ignore it and just continue your normal workflow replacing `git merge development` with `git rebase development`.

Note that because the commit IDs change, if you have already pushed `feature` there will be problems.  You will have to `git push --force` and anyone else working on `feature` will have a hard time pulling.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will your approach work if I do regular "merge" pull on `development`, and then `git rebase development` on `feature` ? The reason is, where I work everyone is merging, and I am not used to rebasing/resolving rebase conflicts.

Comment: @kiruwka Yes, how development gets updated doesn't matter.  Let me edit the answer to clear up what I meant by "pulling from development".

Comment: Accepted. I tried it: 1) first updated my local `development` as usual via `git pull` and then 2) `git rebase development` on feature. Second step did present rebase conflicts, which I had to resolve one by one and apply `git rebase --continue` for each conflicting commit. It was not too much of a problem though, and finally seemed to work ok. However, I did not submit MR after doing this yet, hope this will work fine too : )

Comment: @kiruwka So long as you never pushed the branch before you rebased it, everything will be fine.  Even if you did push it, if you're the only one using it everything will be fine.